# header JPG not showing in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8

On [this site](http://www.annsstudioofdance.com/wp/), the header image displays fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Internet Explorer 8.

If I use IE8's developer tools, and disable the CSS rules specifying max-width: 100%, nothing changes.

**Update**

Turning on Compatibility Mode in IE8 reveals the logo.

However, the navigation menu is floating over the top of it:
[image: Compatibility Mode in IE8]

Comment: Any reason you have the image nested inside a <strong> tag? Not sure that's your issue, but sure doesn't seem right either way...

Comment: What color mode was the JPEG saved in? IE8 will not display JPEGs that have been saved with a CMYK color space. Use RGB instead.

Comment: Compatibility Mode in IE8 is effectively the same as IE7 which will render CMYK JPEGs.

Comment: Thanks @AndréDion.  The image is RGB.